# Illegal instruction (core dumped) with PBC library

Tags: c, coredump

I'm using the following BLS library [PBC](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch02s01.html). Everything works fine within my eclipse environment, but when I try to run the application on a computer it crashes with:

```
 Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I was able to find the problem, but I don't know how to solve it:

```
pairing_t pairing;
char param[1024];
FILE* a = fopen("a.param","r");
size_t count = fread(param, 1, 1024, a);
fclose(a); //File exists!
pairing_init_set_str(pairing, param); //Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I had this problem with two desktops running Ubuntu (up to date). I can't find any documentation if I need to install something despite the GMP library. Further, I compiled the program with static setting. Do I need to install something so a certain "instruction" is known? If you need more information, just ask!

Edit: I just noticed that my eclipse environment where I compile the application uses Ubuntu 12.04 while the other computers run 14.04. Could that be a problem?

Comment: The second parameter must be a zero-terminated string. There is nothing in your code that ensure that `param` is zero-terminated.

Comment: They have another function that is called pairing_init_set_buf that I used before. And I used it like they showed in an example. But I will fix that and try to run it.

Comment: Solution: Yes it was the Ubuntu version. Once I updated it, the program run like it was intended! Whoever will face such a problem: Try to compile the application on target system. If that works you found the problem :)!